# Third line of input not read

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why doesn't it read the third line of input
This is the code that is written in python3. Not much explanation is required as it's very basic programming.

```
n, x = list(map(int, input().split(" ")))
s = []
print(x)
for i in range(0,3):
    s.append(input())
    print(s)
print("hello")
```

Input is :

```
5 3
89 90 78 93 80
90 91 85 88 86
91 92 83 89 90.5
```

Output I got:

```
3
['89 90 78 93 80']
['89 90 78 93 80', '90 91 85 88 86']
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. Did you press Enter at the end of the last line of input?

Comment: No newline..If I add the code works. But i cannot do that because the test cases are predefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the `.split(" ")` to `.split()` and got the output.

Answer (score 0):

You need an additional newline character at the end of your input so that `input()` would recognize the last line as a line.

Comment: No newline..If I add the code works. But i cannot do that because the test cases are predefined